# Redirect output from print function to Text and and disable it

Tags: python, tkinter

how can we redirect the output of the button action to TextBox in Tkinter? And after that TextBox should be grayed out. Here is the sample code I have written which prints the output on the console. I want "hello world" to be printed in the textbox and textbox should be grayed out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x650')
readOnlyText = tk.Text(root)

def testmethod():
    print("hello world-1")

textbox = Text(root,width=75,height=12)
textbox.place(x=60,y=100)

Button(root, text='Submit',command=testmethod,width=10,bg='brown',fg='white').place(x=300,y=350)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `textbox.delete('1.0', END) textbox.insert('1.0', "Hello world-1\n") textbox['state']='disabled' `

Comment: Hi JacksonPro , after clicking on the button action, data from the method should be printed in textbox. I don't want to print by directly using the insert option.

Comment: "data from the method should be redirected" what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To intercept the `print` function, you will need to change the `sys.stdout` target. Refer to the example below

```py
from tkinter import *
from io import StringIO
import sys

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x650')

output=StringIO()
sys.stdout=output

def update():
    textbox['state']='normal'
    textbox.insert(END,output.getvalue())
    output.truncate(0)
    output.seek(0)
    textbox['state']='disabled'
    root.after(100,update)

def testmethod():
    print('Hello World')

textbox = Text(root,width=75,height=12)
textbox.place(x=60,y=100)

button=Button(root, text='Submit',command=testmethod,width=10,bg='brown',fg='white')
button.place(x=300,y=350)

update()

root.mainloop()
```

The `update` function will be called after every `100` milliseconds, which will insert the current value held by `output` and then clear it. The `state` of the `Text` widget should be `normal` to make any changes to its contents, hence the `state` has been toggled in every call.

To restore the output back to the shell, you can call

```py
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Comment: You can also create your own class that will handle the `sys.stdout.write`. It wouldn't need the `io` library.

Comment: Hey AST, but how can we redirect the output to a textbox if we import another python file in testmethod method?: For e.g. If I use os.system('python content.py') in testmethod, then it showing the output to console, not on the textbox? What can be done in this case?

Comment: @Shantanu Using `os.system` is not the same as importing a file, its running another script separately. if you wish to import a file into the current script use `import content`.